# How to make repository be loaded lazily when I start application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

During development, after number of class increased, it take over 2 minutes until application is started.I think it makes our develop efficiency low...

And I found that if we add 'lazyInit=true', If I add this option, most of classes will be loaded lazily, but repositories are loaded even if I add this option.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = LazyApplication.class,lazyInit=true)
@EnableAutoConfiguration(
)
public class LazyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LazyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Actually, our system have more than 300 repository and entity, so I want to make repository lazy too if possible.

How can I make my repository will
Not be loaded when I start application but  loaded when I access to the repository for the first time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`@Order`**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html) annotation on your configuration classes to define load ordering.The highest precedence advice runs first. The lower the number, the higher the precedence.
e.g

```
@Component
@Order(2)
public class MyRepo {
    public String getName() {
        return "some value";
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your advice, I tried this way, but repository still be loaded during initiation timing. which mean, staring time still the same.