# Order of component scanning in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Am new to spring, had defined the ApplicaionConfig.java there I placed the property file details.

```
package com.rao.first;

//
//  import statements
//

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { ApplicationConfig.class  }, basePackages = { "com.rao.first" })
@PropertySources({ 
@PropertySource("file:${webapp.root}/resources/config/application.properties"),
@PropertySource(value = "file:${conf.dir}/someother.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true) })
class ApplicationConfig
{
    @Bean
    ServletContextListener logbackConfigListener()
    {
        return new LogbackConfigListener();

    }
}
```

and defined some controller classes.

```
package com.rao.first.controller;
//
//  import statements
//
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/first")
public class FirstController
{
    private String viewerUrl;

    @Inject
    public FirstController(Environment env)
    {
        this.viewerUrl = env.getProperty("property1");
    }

    //
    //

}
```

But here first controller is executing, after that ApplicaitonConfig is executing, so unable to get the data from property file.

And spring-servlet.xml file configurations are

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rao.first.view" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rao.controller.security" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rao.controller" />
```

Please guide me how can set order of execution?

Comment: you can use `@Order(Ordered.HEIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)`

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I am using `spring 4.2.5`... Ordered interface is not available in this version.

Comment: Then use pure integer number. e.g `@Order(2)`. Remember that The lower the number, the higher the precedence. See the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278128/4423636

Answer (score 0):

You could use [org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation to retrieve values from a properties file.

So your controller class could be like following:

```
package com.rao.first.controller;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
//
//  import statements
//
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/first")
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/rao/app.properties")
public class FirstController
{
    private String viewerUrl;

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    public FirstController()
    {
        this.viewerUrl = env.getProperty("property1");
    }

    //
    //

}
```

I hope it helps you, bye.